# Which one to use? microsoft/azure-cli vs mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cli

There are at least two different(?) docker containers that provide an azure-cli installation:

- [microsoft/azure-cli](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-cli)
- mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli

For the last one I can not find a public docker hub link. This is described [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-cli/blob/master/docs-ref-conceptual/run-azure-cli-docker.md):

> The Azure CLI has migrated to Microsoft Container Registry. Existing
>   tags on Docker Hub are still supported, but new releases will only be
>   available as mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli.

What confuses me is, that `microsoft/azure-cli` is getting still updates. `latest` tag was updated 20 days ago.

I want to execute azure-cli commands on my development laptop.

The question is: which docker container should be used? Which one is more future safe and will get ongoing (feature) updates in future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of curse, the image `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli` is better while it has the new releases. But if the feature you need exists in both images, then I think there is no much different.

But according to where the container you use, there will be some difference. When you run the image locally, both are available. When you run the image in Azure platform, the `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli` is better according to the [Benefits of the Microsoft Container Registry](https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/blog/microsoft-syndicates-container-catalog/).

You can directly pull the image `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli` via the command `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli`, it will work perfectly.

Comment: Where do you get the evidence, that `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli` is more update to date than `microsoft/azure-cli`?

Comment: @Charmin The description that you already had seen. "new releases will only be available as mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli". What else do you want to prove?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`Container Registry`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-registry/) you can use the later, if you are doing it on the local machine, I would recommend you to go with [`docker hub image`](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-cli)

Of course, it's really hard to compare Azure Container Registry with Docker Hub. The advantages of ACR are privacy by default, integration with Azure services. Docker Hub, on the other hand, is being a community hub for image creators and out-of-box integration with GitHub and Bitbucket.

Comment: But why do you recommend that way? Your answer lacks for an explanation.